# XML to create from an oracle query

Tags: xml, oracle, xelement

I wrote below query to generate a xml file

```
 SELECT XMLElement("Providers", 
                   XMLElement("Provider" ,XMLAttributes(
                                        "Unique ID" as "UniqueId"), 
                   XMLElement("ProviderType", "Provider Type"),
                   XMLElement("Specialities",
                   XMLElement("Speciality", "Specialty")),
                   XMLElement("Relationships",
                   XMLElement("Relationship", "Relationship")),
                   XMLElement("ServiceAddress",
                   XMLElement("AddressLine1","P Address Line 1"),
                   XMLElement("AddressLine2","P Address Line 2"), 
                   XMLElement("AddressLine3","P Address Line 3"), 
                   XMLElement("AddressLine4","P Address Line 4"),
                   XMLElement("City","Service city description"),
                   XMLElement("Region","PState_Province_Region"),
                   XMLElement("PostalCode","PPostal Code"),
                   XMLElement("IsoCountryCode","ServiceCountry ISO code")),
                   XMLElement("Contacts",
                        XMLElement("ContactInfo",
                            XMLElement("ContactType","Contact Type"),
                            XMLElement("Name","Contact Name"),
                            XMLElement("Title","Contact Title"),
                            XMLElement("Function","Contact Function"),
                            XMLElement("PhoneNo","Contact Phone Number"),
                            XMLElement("CellNo","Contact Cell Phone Number"),
                            XMLElement("Email","Contact E-mail") ))))
                    AS "RESULT" 
FROM providers_xml
```

but this create seperate xml file for each row in the table provider as below

**file 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Providers>
 -<Provider UniqueId="AA">
  <ProviderType>1</ProviderType>
  -<Specialities>
   <Speciality>210</Speciality>
  </Specialities>
  -<Relationships>
   <Relationship/></Relationships>
  -<ServiceAddress>
   <AddressLine1>ABC</AddressLine1>
   <AddressLine2/><AddressLine3/>
   <AddressLine4/>
   <City>city123</City>
   <Region/>
   <PostalCode/>
   <IsoCountryCode>US</IsoCountryCode>
   </ServiceAddress>
  -<Contacts>
   -<ContactInfo>
    <ContactType>1</ContactType>
    <Name>General Contact</Name>
    <Title/>
    <Function/>
    <PhoneNo/>
    <CellNo/>
    <Email/>
    </ContactInfo>
   </Contacts>
  </Provider>
</Providers>
```

**File 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Providers>
 -<Provider UniqueId="ABC">
  <ProviderType>1</ProviderType>
  -<Specialities>
   <Speciality>100</Speciality>
  </Specialities>
  -<Relationships>
   <Relationship/></Relationships>
  -<ServiceAddress>
   <AddressLine1>zxy</AddressLine1>
   <AddressLine2/><AddressLine3/>
   <AddressLine4/>
   <City>city300</City>
   <Region/>
   <PostalCode/>
   <IsoCountryCode>US</IsoCountryCode>
   </ServiceAddress>
  -<Contacts>
   -<ContactInfo>
    <ContactType>2</ContactType>
    <Name>General Contact</Name>
    <Title/>
    <Function/>
    <PhoneNo/>
    <CellNo/>
    <Email/>
    </ContactInfo>
   </Contacts>
  </Provider>
</Providers>
```

But i need all these files as one as below

```
-<Providers>
     -<Provider UniqueId="AA">
      <ProviderType>1</ProviderType>
      -<Specialities>
       <Speciality>210</Speciality>
      </Specialities>
      -<Relationships>
       <Relationship/></Relationships>
      -<ServiceAddress>
       <AddressLine1>ABC</AddressLine1>
       <AddressLine2/><AddressLine3/>
       <AddressLine4/>
       <City>city123</City>
       <Region/>
       <PostalCode/>
       <IsoCountryCode>US</IsoCountryCode>
       </ServiceAddress>
      -<Contacts>
       -<ContactInfo>
        <ContactType>1</ContactType>
        <Name>General Contact</Name>
        <Title/>
        <Function/>
        <PhoneNo/>
        <CellNo/>
        <Email/>
        </ContactInfo>
       </Contacts>
      </Provider>
     -<Provider UniqueId="ABC">
      <ProviderType>1</ProviderType>
      -<Specialities>
       <Speciality>100</Speciality>
      </Specialities>
      -<Relationships>
       <Relationship/></Relationships>
      -<ServiceAddress>
       <AddressLine1>zxy</AddressLine1>
       <AddressLine2/><AddressLine3/>
       <AddressLine4/>
       <City>city300</City>
       <Region/>
       <PostalCode/>
       <IsoCountryCode>US</IsoCountryCode>
       </ServiceAddress>
      -<Contacts>
       -<ContactInfo>
        <ContactType>2</ContactType>
        <Name>General Contact</Name>
        <Title/>
        <Function/>
        <PhoneNo/>
        <CellNo/>
        <Email/>
        </ContactInfo>
       </Contacts>
      </Provider>
    </Providers>
```

Please help to get the desired o/p

Comment: Sounds like you're after [XMLAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions235.htm)

Comment: `select xmlelement("Providers",xmlagg( 'rest_of_your_sql' )) as result `

Answer (score 0):

Add an XMLAGG clause.

```
 SELECT XMLElement("Providers", 
            **XMLAGG(**
               XMLElement("Provider" ,XMLAttributes(
                                    "Unique ID" as "UniqueId
```